# Creating pixel perfect standard UIBarButtonItem with custom image inside

Tags: iphone, ios, uibarbuttonitem

I've been scratching my head over this for the past couple of hours. Is it possible to create a standard `UIBarButtonItem` with a custom image *inside*? All I want is the standard blue button, but with an image that represents preferences (a screwdriver or cog wheel that I'll create myself) inside of it. I'd rather not use Photoshop to do this, since I'd like every single pixel to be perfect and future proof, in case Apple releases even higher resolution iOS devices.

I've found a wonderful project on GitHub that includes every graphic element shipped with iOS, and I've extracted what appears to be the image Apple itself uses when creating standard `UIBarButtonItems`. Problem is, it can't be resized to the proper dimensions in a way that I know of. In case it's not possible to do what I want with code, then maybe someone can tell me how to use this image.

[GitHub - UIKit-Artwork-Extractor](https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor)

[UINavigationBarDefaultButton@2x.png](http://cl.ly/0W3H1A3n3O1N193M3a3R)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the settings-cog image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create your image, in a single color (only the alpha channel is significant) and use [`initWithImage:style:target:action:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarButtonItem/initWithImage%3astyle%3atarget%3aaction%3a) with the UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered or UIBarButtonItemStyleDone style.

If you want a full-color image, you'll have to use the image you linked. The secret is to resize it by duplicating the "middle" column and row of pixels in the style of an Android [9-patch image](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch), rather than by scaling the entire thing.

Comment: Perhaps I'm doing something wrong, but this doesn't seem to work in iOS 5. I set a bar button item's image in my interface file, and it displays the actual image rather than using its alpha channel as a template.

Answer (score 1):

Images like that are used by making them *stretchable*. Basically, you want only the middle of the image to be stretched when you resize the image, while the left and right cap should not be scaled, to avoid distortion.

```
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"UINavigationBarDefaultButton.png"];
UIImage *stretchableButtonImage = [buttonImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:5 topCapHeight:0];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setBackgroundImage:stretchableButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

In your case however, why don't you just use a `UIBarButtonItem` with the `UIBarButtonItemStyleDone` or `UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered` as its style?